# Agora SDK for puchase API key

Tags: swift, agora.io

I used agora kit for video call and now I want to purchase that. My question is that if I purchase this plan, whether the current API key will change.

Comment: Could you contact Agora to answer this question? It seems to be more of a technical support issue than a general programming question.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a purchasing/licensing support question that should be directed to the vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean by  API key, if you mean the APP ID, it won't be changed after you go production.